# How to make captions align left in bootstrap 5

Tags: html, slider, bootstrap-5

[image: Bootstrap Captions]

How can I acheive this in bootstrap without using so much custom css. I mean without overwriting default bootstrap css.

Edit: My current code (Image is a refrence image)

```
<div class="row align-items-center" style="margin: auto">
<div class="banner" id="home">
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="/img/HP-banner-03.jpg" class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-md-block col-6 text-start text-dark">
                    <h5>First slide label</h5>
                    <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="/img/HP-banner-03.jpg" class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5>Second slide label</h5>
                    <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="/img/HP-banner-03.jpg" class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" alt="...">
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                    <h5>Third slide label</h5>
                    <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can we see what you have for custom code at the moment?

Comment: @LiamMorton added as edit

Comment: So you don't have any css aside from what's in the html? If not I would try changing the padding of the text `padding-left` specifically. but if you do can I see your css too?